# NPM: should I use one of my dependencies' dependencies, or should I explicitly install it into the project at the root level?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

### TL;DR Summary

(I'm using Lodash as an example here, but it could be any other package)

In addition to using Lodash for its own purposes, my application also needs to import JavaScript from an NPM package that I created. The JavaScript in this package relies on Lodash as well. It's possible that each codebase may have installed a different version of Lodash. If JavaScript in my application and JavaScript in the installed package both import the same Lodash functions, then I want to avoid having to bundle two different versions of the same function. I understand that NPM is able to resolve the dependencies and that nothing will break, but the size of my application's JavaScript bundle will continue to grow as each codebase uses functions from different versions of the same libraries. It sounds like the only way to keep the versions in sync is to continuously monitor them and upgrade manually when appropriate, or to use the version provided by the installed package directly, without ever installing it into my application's own `package.json`. Is doing the latter a bad idea and is there no better way?

### Original Question

At my company, we've created a Git repository that houses most of our UI component code. This repository also contains a static site generator, which transforms our UI component code into a "living style guide" website. The purpose of this website is to document and showcase our UI components on the web (similar to how [PatternLab](http://patternlab.io/) works).

We also distribute this code via NPM, so that it can be shared across multiple projects. Each project installs the NPM module as a dependency, then imports the SASS and JavaScript files contained within. The JavaScript has been written in ES6 and has not been bundled or transpiled. We've intentionally chosen not to distribute browser-ready code. Instead, each project is responsible for compiling its own SASS and bundling/transpiling its own JavaScript.

Most of our UI component JavaScript is simple and does not depend on any third-party libraries, so it's easy to import into our projects. However, some of our newer, more complex components rely on NPM packages such as Lodash, which presents a problem.

Obviously, we need to install Lodash in order for the static site generator to showcase our Lodash-reliant components inside of a web browser. Similarly, projects that consume the NPM package will also need to install Lodash, in order to create instances of these same components. This forces us to install Lodash twice: once in the UI component project, then again in the project that consumes the NPM package. This is problematic because the two projects could potentially install different versions of Lodash, which could lead to compatibility issues and/or increase the size of our JavaScript bundle.

One solution that I've discovered is to include Lodash under `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`, in the UI component project. This way, when external projects install the UI component NPM module, Lodash will be installed along with it. This gives the project "free" access to Lodash without needing to explicitly install it itself. This is possible because NPM installs packages in a single, flat directory hierarchy, so it doesn't seem to matter if your project installs a package directly or if one of its dependencies exposes it as a dependency in it's own `package.json`. This eliminates version conflicts, since you don't have to install the package twice.

My question is, does this violate NPM best practices or is this how NPM is intended to work? After reading the NPM documentation and Googling for answers, it doesn't seem like this should be a problem. However, if what I'm suggesting is a bad idea, how else can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Here's a quick visual aid:

```
main.js
node_modules/
  lodash/
  foo/
    bar.js
    node_modules/
      lodash/
```

`main.js` imports and uses Lodash. It also imports `foo/bar.js`, which uses Lodash too, but a potentially different version. Both files are ES6. `main.js` gets bundled and transpiled before being sent to the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if is something you are directly using you should specify it in your `package.json`. it will be installed anyways but this way it will ensure that if your dependency removes that package as a dependency your project won't break

Comment: But what if I install a newer version of the package? Won't I end up with 2 different, potentially conflicting versions in my `node_modules` directory? If both my parent project and the package I've installed rely on Lodash, for example, couldn't I end up bundling two versions of the same library and increasing the amount of code that my users have to download in their browsers?

Comment: @MarkPlewis - If your package.json specifies the same version of the module for both your directly loaded one and for the one used by another package, then the modern version of NPM is smart enough to only download and store one of them.  If the two separate package.json files specify different versions, then NPM will do as instructed and get two different versions and those will both be used by the modules that requested each version.  This allows modules to co-exist that don't all rely on the same version of some sub-module.

Comment: I need to find a way to guarantee that the versions remain in sync (which I don't believe is possible?), or rely directly on the version that my dependency has installed for me, so that I don't have to install it a second time.

Comment: in that case the best option would be to use shrinkwrap and lock your dependencies in which case it won't matter if the dependency is in package.json or not. but it will still be good to have it for clarity and documentation purposes. but if you don't want to and you have 2different versions of a module they should not conflict. your application would require the one under general node_modules and the dependency would required the one under its own node_modules. don't forget before npm 3 thats how everything worked with nested dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @DayanMorenoLeon, but using shrinkwrap isn't going to help me avoid bundling multiple copies of the same functions, from different versions of the same library. It's starting to sound like I have no other option than the hack that I've come up with. I added a shorter "TL;DR" description to my original question.

Comment: when you use shrinkwrap you lock the versions of your dependencies making it impossible for them to update w/o you noticing. that will ensure that your lodash versions will always be in sync. make a shrinkwrap file of your current project and check what lodash version is being used. then add that t your package.json for documentation purposes and that is it. when shrinkwrap file is detected package.json is not important for dependencies as is all driven by the shrinkwrap file. i a, failing to see how would this not help you

Comment: Thanks @DayanMorenoLeon. Yes, that will lock things down, but Lodash will still need to be manually updated in each of the projects when we consciously decide to upgrade. When we release a new version of our NPM package, I suppose we could document in the release notes that the Lodash version has been bumped up, so consuming projects will also need to bump up their Lodash version to match. I was hoping there would be a way to automate this or eliminate the need to maintain parallel installs altogether though.